# Should location be required or recommended in questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've seen this topic come up a few times here and there over the past week or two, but I guess no one asked yet.

Location can sometimes make a big difference in what hardware is available in a certain region, so my thinking is we should start strongly encouraging the inclusion of a general location (country usually works) so people can recommend hardware easier. If we really wanted clarification, we could *require* a location.

Including a location can also clear up any question of what currency the OP uses. A good example of this is the distinction between U.S. and Canadian dollars.

So should location be a part of questions on this site?

Comment: A good example is [this question](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/355/a-good-monitor-as-the-main-one-of-a-two-monitor-setup). The OP lives in Germany.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Recommended, not required.**

It's not absolutely essential to have the location in a question - unlike the specific requirements that we do mandate, location doesn't influence what product fits the poster's specification. For that reason, we shouldn't be *requiring* a location.

However, there are going to be plenty of cases where a location helps - in distinguishing currencies (though one assumes that the OP will specify their native currency in any pricing requirements they have), in working out what's available where, etc. For *that* reason, we should *recommend* that a location is included, because it will help us give better answers tailored to the specific situation.

Comment: Is it possible to have location as a field when they are asking the question?  That way it pushes them to put forth that information.  I am seeing this becoming an issue much more often. I am not sure if this is something that can even be modified on SE.

Comment: @Jeff No, that's not currently possible.