# Should this site have region tags to help region specific reccomendations

Tags: discussion, tags

Following [this comment](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272/what-to-do-regarding-market-region-specific-hardware-q-a#comment451_274) and related question.

Since a lot of recommendation questions are region specific , both in terms of suppliers availability, as well as price and currency , should some kind of a region-base tag system should be implemented ? and If yes, than how ?

I do know that a region-specific tag system might be strange, but on the other hand , it will help a lot in filtering specific regions or countries to see the best fit hardware that is available in your location and from a local distributor .

On the other hand - Nowadays where everything can be purchased online, and shipped virtually everywhere , does local-only recommendations still have the same value ?

Comment: I agree with the answers from Andy and Undo below for the most part so I won't add a "me too" answer, but I wanted to add that I voted you up too - it's a perfectly valid thing to ask and deserves an answer on meta, so not sure why it has been downvoted

Comment: @AdamComerford On meta, voting is different than on the main site. It's meant to express agreement or disagreement - if you disagree, you downvote, if you agree, you upvote.

Comment: I get the concept but when the question is asking whether something should be done or not, I prefer to vote based on whether I think it was a worthy question and then up vote or write the answer to express my opinion. Down voting valid questions discourages the very discussion that meta is trying to foster

Comment: “a lot of recommendation questions are region specific” [citation needed]. Most computer hardware can be used anywhere in the world, and can be bought online from anywhere if you pay for shipping. Currency isn't a discriminating factor, just convert.

Comment: @Gilles -  The citation is given in the linked question, and also, I wwrote myself that it can be available, but then - back to the linked question - how to deal with it ? the question is not about  shipping. The question is about tags or filtering system to help avoid region or location questions under the assumption that I can not answer it correctly if I take into account the factors mentioned in the [voted answer](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/272/what-to-do-regarding-market-region-specific-hardware-q-a#comment451_274) .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen I'm not seeing an example of a question that would have different answers in different regions. Would you mind being more explicit?

Comment: @Gilles look [HERE](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/528/recommendation-for-prosumer-3d-printer) which is the original reference . the OP asked specifically in the Australian market . ( read comments also ) . In my region the product is available,. In the OP region it is not .

Answer (score 6):

I do not think region specific tags are necessary. The idea of the site isn't to put a user in contact with a retailer. It's to recommend a hardware product that meets their requirements. It is *helpful* to link to a retailer, but not necessary.

---

Both parties in a post should take care to provide relevant details about where they are located. My default assumption about a user's location is generally based on the currency they provide for their budget. If they provide a budget in dollars, I assume they are in the United States. If they provide Euros, I assume they are in Europe. If they provide another currency, then I assume they are in a location that uses that currency. If someone is asking a question and provides a currency and a location that don't match (ie. dollars and they are traveling to Europe), then I assume the explicitly mentioned location.

While a link to a retailer is not necessary, it does make an answer "better". Along the same line of reasoning, a link to a local retailer (or localized online merchant) is probably better than a link to a global merchant, simply due to pricing.

Tags for regions, though, are not useful. They are too broad (ie. "United States", "Europe", "Asia"), because of the huge geographic differences, tax laws, supply in specific regions, or even different countries in the region. Alternatively, they can become to focused (ie. "Chicago", "London", "Seoul"), in which case they are useless because a product available in Chicago is probably available in Detroit. The same is true with London and Paris or Seoul and Tokyo.

---

As someone who wants to provide recommendations, you simply need to provide a recommendation that is helpful. If you know a product is hard to get in a certain region, make a note of that.

Comment: I am not sure you can assume location by Currency - I myself use USD but that is because I assume that most people will understand it's value ( as opposed to RMB, CNY, HKD, ILS, SWF, etc ) . I do not expect people to do exchange rte adjustments .

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that we aren't here to provide recommendations on where to buy a product, but on what product to buy. If a requirement is that the hardware be available for purchase locally in the North Pole, then the question should state that.

However, you have to remember, the asker is just one person who will profit from the recommendation they receive. If a question asks for something available in the North Pole for eight hundred north-pole-dollars, I wouldn't hesitate to provide a recommendation for something *not* available locally in the North Pole.

This would include proper warning about it not being available locally, but otherwise be a normal answer. Two reasons for this:

1. That answer might not be of particular use to the asker, who might be under time constraints and need the hardware *now*. However, the vast majority of our audience comes from Google - who probably aren't under the same constraints.
2. Most people in countries that don't have hardware available locally have figured out how to get around it - have someone in the EU/US buy it and ship it to them, Bitcoin, etc. My answer could still be helpful, if slightly more inconvenient.

Note that I would only post this if it matched all the other requirements - and I still might expect downvotes. That's a tradeoff everyone has to make: sometimes something doesn't match every requirement: how far are we willing to compromise?

In light of that (and I know I swerved off topic a little bit), I'd argue that **country tags would be meta tags**: tags that describe the question, not the hardware the person is seeking.

Comment: I would argue the same like you, but than you should also read the linked [question](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/272/what-to-do-regarding-market-region-specific-hardware-q-a#comment451_274)  and answers - If we should only answer questions with region specific details - than how to avoid wasting time reading it ? Also , If ( Like I also think ) The region is not important - maybe the policy of allowing people to ask region / budget is wrong ..